# Error while saving floats to PostgreSQL from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I just recently made the switch over to PostgreSQL.. and just wondering about this issue:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "bathrooms" is of type double precision but expression is of type    character varying at character 161
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
: INSERT INTO "properties" ("address", "bathrooms", "bedrooms", "city", "country", "created_at",     "description", "name", "state", "updated_at", "zip") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11) RETURNING "id"
```

Migration looks like this:

```
class CreateProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :properties do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.string :address
   t.string :city
   t.string :state
   t.string :zip
   t.string :country
   t.float :bedrooms
   t.float :bathrooms
   t.string :country
   t.text :description

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: I think you pass a string to column "bathrooms" as this is said in the error. Try to check the value, which is passed to "bathrooms". It must be of type float, double or int.

Comment: Right, but I thought the casting was handled by ActiveRecord, it doesn't make much sense here what the best practice is for this case.

Comment: Why do you have a float for bedrooms/bathrooms instead of integer? Surely you can't have 1.5 bathrooms... I don't know how well Rails can cast string to float (without you having supplied precision argument), but integers it should be able to do.

Comment: Actually yes you can, you could have 2.5 bathrooms, that means the .5 is a partial bathroom, no shower/tub. At least that's the convention in USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched the **float** to decimal, it seems PostgreSQL is fine with that implicit cast now?

Either way the error is gone, thanks

Comment: some implicit casts are respected still (usually between numeric types)